# What causes Google search to display a byline for a GitHub repo?

Tags: github, google-search

When I do a Google Search on certain GitHub repositories, I see a byline and a date on the third line (following the URL).  For example, the "by D Stark - 2016" line in the following screenshot.  What causes this information to be displayed and what is the root source of the information?

[image]

Comment: I ask in part because in this case, the name in question is not a contributor to the repository and the date seems arbitrary.

Comment: A Google search that can be used to generate the example above is "Chapel GitHub"

Answer (score 2):

The author at the top is decorated with `itemprop="author"` which I believe trigger this schema http://schema.org/author.

Edit: if you copy-paste the HTML into https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool you'll be able to see everything that is parsed. Marking HTML elements is one way to do it, another one is to build special json elements that contain this data. Ref https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data

Comment: Are you referring to the HTML of the page that the Google search entry is indexing?  (in this case, GitHub's page?)  Searching its source, I'm not seeing the string 'Stark' anywhere in it (for either the live page at GitHub nor Google's cached copy of it).  The author itemprop line looks like this:  `<span class="author" itemprop="author"><a href="/chapel-lang" class="url fn" rel="author">chapel-lang</a></span>`.  Pasting the HTML into the testing tool, I'm not seeing Stark there either.

Comment: Good point, the plot tickens, the only mention to Stark that I can find is in the only "authors" files that is a third party file https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/blob/master/third-party/qthread/qthread-src/AUTHORS

Comment: This is very weird because google tool itself finds the author in the same way I thought https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fchapel-lang%2Fchapel and even 2016 is a bit too old, it's been updated all the time since!

Comment: "the only mention to Stark that I can find is in the only "authors" files" -- right, same here.  And the date stamp on that file is 2016.  But it seems odd / arbitrary that Google would use that file in the search summary.